# curl_multi, guzzle 6, rolling_curl что посоветуете?

Tags: многопоточность, curl, guzzle

Всем привет! уже которій час бюсь над єтим вопросом, и толком ничего не могу сделать. Может кто подскажет)

есть АПИ поставщика, по которому достаю данные о товарах в категории.
На один GET запрос он отдает только 1000 товаров.
а товаров , напрмер 10000 в категории. 
Обычным curl - это достаточно долго (категорий только около 1000)
вот и стоит задача, максимально ускорить процесс получения данных из АПИ.

curl_multi - почему то отдает не все запросы, часть из них возвращаются пустыми.

guzzle 6 (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/index.html) и rolling_curl - пока не смог разобрать как использовать мультизапросы в них.

Буду очень благодарен за подсказки.

Спасибо!

Comment: Вы ищете туториал, а это, по-моему, офф-топик. Даже если и нет, то в вопросе отсутствует [MCVE].

Comment: В туториале Guzzle понятным английским языком написано про Pool и Concurrent Request. Пройдите по туториалу, встретите проблему - тогда и спрашивайте предметно.